# linear condition not satisfied - MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, linear-programming, solver

I using excel to make a class schedule for instructors using linear programming technique with Solver

I have are:
4 instructors
5 weekdays
4 hours four each day

I need to assign each instructor to class with satisfying the numbers of hours required for the week, and the preference for each day.
the schedule has preference column that calculated using this function
=IF(COUNTIF(B5:Q5,">0"),4,0) this means if the instructor has a class in this day it assigns it to 4 as a preference otherwise it assigns it to 0

also, I assign the preference as a constraint that should be 5 or equal to it.

my objective function is to maximize the employee's stratification by sum the preference for each day

when I applied the Solver it gave me that the linearity condition required by this LP solver are not satisfied. and the Linearity Repost gave me that MAX function are not linear. what is the problem?

Is there another way to calculate the objective function?

This is the excel file
drive.google.com/open?id=0B2elSalAvlEKVHU2Z0RTQzF3dUE

Comment: Your formula `=IF(COUNTIF(B5:Q5,">0"),4,0)` is not linear, so you cannot use the `Simplex-LP` method. Did you try with the other solver methods (i.e. GRG non-linear or Evolutionary)?

Comment: yes I tried to use GRG and it works but it give me float number and I need a binary number, 1 if the instructor has a class and 0 otherwise

Comment: can I have another formula to calculate the preference using LP?

Comment: There's certainly some way or another to do so. I don't know the details of your model to suggest one. What if you try something like `=0.25 * SUM(B5:Q5)`?

Comment: what do you mean by 0.25?

Comment: just a coefficient... trying to replace the formula with something linear. The value 0.25 is not much important.

Comment: I need to assign a preference for each employee if I used this formula how can I do this?

Comment: This depends on your model. Where do these preferences come from? Usually you should ask them their preferences, or take a look to their old schedule etc. For instance I thought that you had it, in the form of an `IF` formula and I suggested some way to change it.

Comment: If you have some almost-complete model but has the only problem of non-linearity, post some data so we can try to figure out how to linearizr it.

Comment: The preferences that I have are for a college 
how can I upload the data?

Comment: I made the model with all the constraints and preferences

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2elSalAvlEKVHU2Z0RTQzF3dUE

Here is the excel file
look at the schedule sheet

Comment: Again try to set the formula of preference proportional. for example when the preference for some employee/day is 2, use something like `=2 * SUM(B5:Q5)`. This linearizes your preferences calculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help... you helped me

Comment: most likely the result was a float because you did not use integer or binary constraints. I'd try adding binary constraints to all variables (I am guessing they are yes/no decisions) and then also change the formula
 =IF(COUNTIF(B5:Q5,">0"),4,0) 
to
=4*sum(b5:q5)
HTH